# Best method to analyse longitudinal recurrent count data

Tags: survival, poisson-distribution, panel-data, generalized-estimating-equations, recurrent-events

I want to analyze count data, more specifically number of prescriptions over 10 years. My first idea was to use the GEE Poisson. However, after reading some papers about recurrent history analysis I got confused about the best method to use. I'm confused about whether I should use the GEE Poisson, or the PWP counting process model or a frailty models.

Can someone shed more light into this or recommend some books, articles? I will be very appreciated.

Thank you all!

Comment: GEE models are usually easy to implement and I like their simplicity.  I'd recommend going with that, based on the limited information you've provided in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This book by Therneau and Grambsch (http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) might be useful. The book is quite advanced but they do have a very nice section regarding your question about which model to choose. Especially, when to use PWP/conditional, Poisson, etc.., and how to structure your data accordingly.

Comment: Can you say something about the strategies they discuss? How would they solve the OP's problem? Etc. At present, this is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the "OP" problem. However, given the provided information I think that the AG(Andersen-Gill) approach would be most suitable. If the recurrent events are of the same same type... If not, there are other approaches discussed in the book. 

This (http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/politics-international-relations/research-methods-politics/event-history-modeling-guide-social-scientists) book might also be of interest for Pavid.

Comment: Thank you! I also like that book. But I actually realized that in this case I can't use PWP since I don't have the exact time each event last. I have the dates for each prescription but the duration of the prescription is not clear for the data. Since it will depend how many time per day you use the medication. For instance, a tablet with 60 pills may last two months if one has to take one per day and one month if it's prescribed twice a day. Therefore, the recurrent event models are not suitable in this case.

Comment: @pavid I can't say anything about your specific subject (I'm in social sciences) but I've had data with countries or individuals where I didn't have stop-time for each subject. They get censored then. In my opinion, it's a bigger problem if you don't have a start-time observation – then you have really big problems if you want to use survival/event history analysis. Good luck!